# How to create temporary files in php to send them by email?

Tags: php, pdf

I have this code that allows me to retrieve a string from a base64 encoded XML file.
I put it in a TXT file, then I decode it to obtain the desired PDF.
Then I send this PDF as an attachment and insert the base64 string in the database. Then I delete the TXT file and PDF from the folders.

Everything works correctly. But I would like a solution to not create these files on the server and then delete them.

I am looking for a more secure solution, I tried the `tmpfile` function but the file is not sent by mail because it is deleted directly after.

Can you help me?

```
<?php

            //Function to keep only the content of the <GraphicImage> tags
            function multiSplit($string)
                {
                    $output = array();
                    $cols = explode("<GraphicImage>", $string);

                foreach ($cols as $col)
                {
                    $dashcols = explode("</GraphicImage>", $col);
                    $output[] = $dashcols[0];
                }
                
                return $output;
            }

            $envoi = $submission_id.'_envoi';
            
            //We put the content of the tags in the variable $DHL
            $DHL = multiSplit($output);

            //We create two unique file names  
            $filename1 = $envoi.'.txt';
            $filename2 = $envoi.'.pdf';

            //We write the content of the tags in the txt file 
            $file1 = "D:/Data/Sites/sav/API_label/TXT/$filename1";                       
            file_put_contents($file1, print_r($DHL[1], true) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

            
            $pdf_base64 = $file1;
            //Get File content from txt file
            $pdf_base64_handler = fopen($pdf_base64,'r');
            $pdf_content = fread ($pdf_base64_handler,filesize($pdf_base64));
            fclose ($pdf_base64_handler);
            //Decode pdf content
            $pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);
            //Write data back to pdf file
            $pdf = fopen ("D:/Data/Sites/sav/API_label/PDF/$filename2",'w');
            fwrite ($pdf,$pdf_decoded);
            //close output file
            fclose ($pdf);
            // echo 'Done';

             //SendGrid Part
             $email = new Mail();
             $email->setFrom("test@test.com", "Sender");
             $email->addTo("$EMAIL", "Recipient");
             $email->setSubject("Etiquettes DHL");
             $email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>Hello</strong>");
 
             $file_encoded = base64_encode(file_get_contents("D:/Data/Sites/sav/retours/API_label/PDF/$filename2"));
             $email->addAttachment($file_encoded, "application/pdf", "$filename2", "attachment");
 
 
             $sendgrid = new \SendGrid('SG.m7481IOix24');
             try {
                 $response = $sendgrid->send($email);

             } catch (Exception $e) {
                 // echo 'Caught exception: ' .  $e->getMessage() . "\n";
             }   

             //Insertion of the values in the database
             try {
                // Connect to db
                $db = new db('mysql:dbname=jotform; host=localhost', 'user', 'password');
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                // Set SQL
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO DHL (submission_id, formID, identite, email, adresse, telephone, label_envoi, commercial_invoice) 
                VALUES (:submission_id, :formID, :NOM, :EMAIL, :ADRESSE, :TELEPHONE, :file_encoded, :COMMERCIAL_INVOICE)';

                // Prepare query
                $query = $db->prepare($sql);

                // Execute query
                $query->execute(array(':submission_id' => $submission_id, ':formID' => $formID, ':NOM' => $NOM, ':EMAIL' => $EMAIL, ':ADRESSE' => $ADRESSE, ':TELEPHONE' => $TELEPHONE, 
                ':file_encoded' => $file_encoded, ':COMMERCIAL_INVOICE' => $COMMERCIAL_INVOICE));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            } 
            
            //Deleting txt and pdf files
            //PDF
            unlink("D:/Data/Sites/sav/API_label/PDF/$filename2");

            //TXT
            unlink("D:/Data/Sites/sav/API_label/TXT/$filename1");
```

Comment: I can't see that writing to a file is achieving anything. Why not put the print_r output into a variable instead of a file? Also it doesn't seem like any of this generates PDF data

Comment: You want me to replace the TXT file with a variable? But in the end the decoded PDF file will still be a physical file to create it right? The decoded file is a PDF file

Comment: I can put screenshots of the txt and pdf file if you want @ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood something, it seems like these two temporary files don't add any value and can be removed - instead you can just directly use the variables you wrote to the files as the inputs to the next steps of the process.

This version should complete the same process without writing to any files:

```
//Function to keep only the content of the <GraphicImage> tags
function multiSplit($string) {
  $output = array();
  $cols = explode("<GraphicImage>", $string);

  foreach($cols as $col) {
    $dashcols = explode("</GraphicImage>", $col);
    $output[] = $dashcols[0];
  }

  return $output;
}

$envoi = $submission_id.'_envoi';
$filename2 = $envoi.'.pdf';

//We put the content of the tags in the variable $DHL
$DHL = multiSplit($output);

//We write the content of the tags
$print1 = print_r($DHL[1], true).PHP_EOL;

//Decode pdf content
$pdf_decoded = base64_decode($print1);

//SendGrid Part
$email = new Mail();
$email->setFrom("test@test.com", "Sender");
$email->addTo("$EMAIL", "Recipient");
$email->setSubject("Etiquettes DHL");
$email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>Hello</strong>");

$file_encoded = base64_encode($pdf_decoded);
$email->addAttachment($file_encoded, "application/pdf", "$filename2", "attachment");

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('SG.m7481IOix24');

try {
  $response = $sendgrid->send($email);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  // echo 'Caught exception: ' .  $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

//Insertion of the values in the database
try {
  // Connect to db
  $db = new db('mysql:dbname=jotform; host=localhost', 'user', 'password');
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  // Set SQL
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO DHL (submission_id, formID, identite, email, adresse, telephone, label_envoi, commercial_invoice)
 VALUES(:submission_id,:formID,:NOM,:EMAIL,:ADRESSE,:TELEPHONE,:file_encoded,:COMMERCIAL_INVOICE)';

  // Prepare query
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);

  // Execute query
  $query->execute(array(':submission_id' => $submission_id, ':formID' => $formID, ':NOM' => $NOM, ':EMAIL' => $EMAIL, ':ADRESSE' => $ADRESSE, ':TELEPHONE' => $TELEPHONE, ':file_encoded' => $file_encoded, ':COMMERCIAL_INVOICE' => $COMMERCIAL_INVOICE));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

It's unclear to me why you use `base64_decode` to read the first file, since there's no evidence of it having been base64-encoded to begin with (it was just the result of a print_r statement on some XML, as far as I can see). Therefore I've also removed that.

Comment: I just tried your code but unfortunately no PDF file is created when I run it...

Comment: You mean there is no attachment on the email?

Comment: No email is sent and in my database no line is inserted either

Comment: Do you get any kind of exception? I notice you have commented out one of the pieces of code which would show you an exception. Maybe enable that again and see if it reports anything. According to https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#attachments, this code should be ok for creating an attachment

Comment: An oversight of parenthesis on my part sorry. So the email and the pdf arrive well but the pdf is impossible to open with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC it tells me it is damaged

Comment: The only other difference I can see is I didn't use `. PHP_EOL` when I created `$print1`, equivalent to what was written to the txt file. Maybe it's that.

Comment: So I have to add `$print1 = base64_decode(print_r($DHL[1], true). PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX));` to test ?

Comment: No, only the bit I actually mentioned. The other bits i.e. - `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX` - are options about how the file is written to which clearly aren't relevant. (If you're not sure what those bits of code are for, you should be consulting the PHP manual)

Comment: Ok I add that the `. PHP_EOL` then

Comment: Still the same mistake even with the addition of this...

Comment: I found the problem! In the first line there is no need to decode it since we write the string in the variable so we just have to put `$print1 = (print_r($DHL[1], true). PHP_EOL);` and it works for the insertion in the database and the sending by mail!

Comment: Well I did mention that in the answer... :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer now to incorporate that change :-)

Comment: Thanks for the changes, it's ok :)